# Problem With Code: Pulling Information from All Questions in a Day

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer

I have the following [code](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/497583/all-questions-from-the-last-n-days?lastNdays=10) that I adapted from another person's code for my specific purpose of reputation statistics on the math.stackexchange platform.

```
-- lastNdays: enter an integer "retrieve only post from the lastNdays"

declare @lastNdays int
set @lastNdays = ##lastNdays:int?10##

select *
from Posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where 
p.PosttypeId=1
and p.CreationDate >= dateadd(day, -@lastNdays, getdate())
and u.reputation < 250
and u.reputation > 100

order by dateadd(day, -@lastNdays, getdate())
```

While the code runs fine, there are two problems with the results that I have a problem fixing:

1. It does not pull data from the last N days in that I get data from 5/29/2016 to bits of 6/5/2016.
2. While I want to order the data by the day at which the questions were posted, I get some random scatter of dates (probably because of the dates at which the answers were posted)

How can I fix this?

Comment: In regards to 1 - SEDE gets updated once a week. It is not realtime.

Comment: The first is unfixable - for the data explorer, the last date is the date of its last update, which happens weekly.

Comment: Why are you sorting using `order by dateadd(day, -@lastNdays, getdate())`? I have no idea what you expect that to return. What exactly do you want to sort by?

Comment: I just want the data to be presented in chronological order.

Comment: Then you should sort by the post creation date. `order by p.CreationDate`.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my clumsiness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It does not pull data from the last N days

SEDE is updated once a week, meaning that the latest data you can get will be the update time.

> While I want to order the data by the day at which the questions were posted

So you should use that in your `order by` clause:

```
order by p.CreationDate
```